# Disabling incremental linking from msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, protocol-buffers

I'm building protobufers for windows, using VS2010 using msbuild e.g. only console, no gui interaction. However I'm running into issues when generating the executables. I get the following errors:

```
(Link target) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
```

The problem is with incremental linking (/INCREMENTAL). My question is how can I disable that when running msbuild and not by editing the .sln/vcproj file. I tried `msbuild /p:incremental=no` to no avail.

Comment: What *exactly* are you linking?  A very common mistake is to try to link a DLL instead of the DLL's import library.

Comment: I'm using whatever the default is from the project. Because I'm testing I tried building the project with VS2008 - no problems. Then I tried it with VS2010 and I got this problem, turning of incremental linking seems to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property that controls it is called `LinkIncremental`. E.g.:

```
msbuild MyProject.vcxproj /p:LinkIncremental=false
```